# Call a javascript function continuously until condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call a javascript function continuously until a condition is satisfied. I have a rest service which sends me a percentage.
I want my javascript to call this REST service continuously until I get a percentage as 100%. When it gets to 100% it should stop.

Overall structure is like below
1)I have a table which has a cell which displays progress.

```
 Packets                 percent    
 abc                       10%
 efs                       13%
```

So when this table will load, a call will go to a function present in javascript which will call the rest service, and this function should be called continuously until percentage is 100%.

Should I use recursive calls? and is function inside function possible?

Comment: *"Should I use recursive calls? And is function inside function possible?"* No and yes. Please show your current function.

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? How are you currently making a request to the server? Simply stop doing sending a request when you get 100% as response.

Comment: What is response from server ?

Comment: @guest271314:Response from the server is the percentage

Comment: @FelixKling:I have a function createTable(){ here I create a tables using jquery,and when creating one of the cells ,i make a function call to the rest which gets me the percentage and then i put the percentage in the cell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function calls condFunc which should return true when condition is met. When that happens readyFunc is called. checkInterval sets checking rate in milliseconds

```
       var wait = function(condFunc, readyFunc, checkInterval) {
            var checkFunc = function() {
                if(condFunc()) {
                    readyFunc(); 
                }
                else
                {
                    setTimeout(checkFunc, checkInterval);
                }
            };
            checkFunc();
        };
```

Usage:

```
       wait(
            function() { return new Date().getSeconds() == 10; }, 
            function() { console.log("Done"); },
            100
        );
```

prints "Done" when current time is 10 seconds after minute

Comment: awesome this helped me a lot ,thans a lot Maksym

Answer (score 1):

If response from server is `0` through `100` can try using `.each()` ,  `.load()` or `$.get()`

```
function progress() {
  el = this;
  $.get("/path/to/rest/call", function(data) {
    el.textContent = data + "%";
    // define conditions for next request
    if (data < 100 /* conditions */) {
      progress.call(el)
    }
  })
}

$("table tr").each(function() {
  progress.call(this)
})
```

Comment: so should I do this way
function populateTable(){
$("table tr").each(function() {
  progress.call(this)
})
}
function progress() {
  $(this).load(function(data) {
    $(this).text(function(_, text) {
      return parseInt(text) + "%"
    })
    if (data < 100) {
      progress.call(this)
    }
  })
}

Comment: @asj177 Does `js` at post return expected results ?

Comment: and where should I place the rest call ?

Comment: @asj177 `.load()` is the ajax call; see updated post , http://api.jquery.com/load ; could alternatively use `$.get()`